# Repeat audio in html crashes browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a html file, when i click a play button an audio has to play continuously.
I've tried this javascript, it plays audio repeatedly with 1 second interval for next play, but finally crashes the browser. I need solution for this issue.

```
function playaudio(){
 var audio =  document.getElementById('audio');
 audio.src = "";
 audio.src = "Beep_Small.wav";
 audio.load();
 audio.play();
 audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){
  this.currentTime = 0;
  setTimeout('playaudio()', 1000);
 }, false);
}
```

Html file looks like this,

```
<audio id="audio" >
    <source id="wav3Source" type="audio/x-wav" src=''></source>
</audio>

<input type="button" onclick="playaudio()" value="Play" />
```

Comment: In firefox browser and am not tested in chrome browser.

Comment: create a jsfiddle for it plz

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an **additional** event listener *every single time* that `playaudio()` is called.  You only need to add the event listener once.

```
// wrap in anonymous function to minimize global variable pollution
(function(){
  var audio;
  function playaudio(){
    if (!audio) {
      audio =  document.getElementById('audio');
      audio.src = "Beep_Small.wav";
      audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){
        // this.currentTime = 0; // I don't think this line really does anything
        setTimeout(playaudio, 1000);
      }, false);
    }

    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
  // export the function to the window object
  window.playaudio = playaudio;
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code fragment. You were calling the playaudio() function again and again, I guess that was causing the browser memory to overflow. The play audio function had the audio.load() function as well. I have used the audio.play(); function only in the setTimeout call.

```
 var audio;
 function playaudio(){
   audio =  document.getElementById('audio');
   audio.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3";
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
   audio.addEventListener('ended', function (){
      this.currentTime = 0;
      setTimeout('audio.play();', 1000);
   }, false);
};
```

check this fiddle as well. http://jsfiddle.net/tPL9j/2/